# Surveys of relational algebra and calculus

Tags: ct.category-theory, database-theory

Can anyone point me to short survey articles of mathmatical expositions of Codd's relational algebra and calculus (from database theory)?

I suspect there's some straightforward categorical interpretation of these.  (NB I'm aware of David Spivak's[1] intriguing application of category theory to databases, but I'm after an application to the specific models of relational algebra and calculus themselves).

[1] http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/

Comment: I hope you will get suitable answers to this question.  Afterwards, there is a general theory of relation algebras and cylindric algebras developed by Alfred Tarski and his followers which may interest you.  The original literature can be somewhat terse, so I recommend a web search before you tackle it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.24 